# JavaScript calculator just returns "NaN"

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm making a calculator for a game I play and whenever I run it, it just returns "NaN" for two values, only one of the values actually returns as it should. The two values that return NaN are the ones that run through switch statements and I found that the values you get from the switch statements are undefined so I think that's where it goes wrong. I tried looking for other questions like this on StackOverflow and I found some but their answers didn't work for me.

```js
var iron_cost = 0
var string_cost = 0
var spider_e_cost = 0
var tami_1_amount = 0
var tami_2_amount = 0
var tami_1_tier = 0
var tami_2_tier = 0
var ta_per_min_1 = 0
var ta_per_min_2 = 0
var cpt_tpc = 0
var cph_tpc = 0
var cpd_tpc = 0

function calculate_tpc() {
  var string_cost = document.getElementById("string_tpc").value;
  var spider_e_cost = document.getElementById("spider_eye_tpc").value;
  var iron_cost = document.getElementById("iron_tpc").value;
  var tami_1_tier = document.getElementById("minions_tier_1_tpc").value;
  var tami_2_tier = document.getElementById("minions_tier_2_tpc").value;
  var tami_1_amount = document.getElementById("minions_1_tpc").value;
  var tami_2_amount = document.getElementById("minions_2_tpc").value;
  var step1 = string_cost * 3.16;
  var step2 = iron_cost * 0.2;
  var step3 = step1 + step2 + spider_e_cost;
  switch (tami_1_tier) {
    case 1:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2;
      break;
    case 2:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2;
      break;
    case 3:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 4:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 5:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 6:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 7:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 8:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 9:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 10:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 11:
      var ta_per_min_1 = 6;
      break;
  }
  switch (tami_2_tier) {
    case 1:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2;
      break;
    case 2:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2;
      break;
    case 3:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 4:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 5:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 6:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 7:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 8:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 9:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 10:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 11:
      var ta_per_min_2 = 6;
      break;
  }
  var step4 = ta_per_min_1 * tami_1_amount;
  var step5 = ta_per_min_2 * tami_2_amount;
  var step6 = step4 + step5;
  var step7 = step6 * step3;
  var step8 = step7 * 60;
  var step9 = step8 * 24;
  document.getElementById("cpt_tpc").innerHTML = step3;
  document.getElementById("cph_tpc").innerHTML = step8;
  document.getElementById("cpd_tpc").innerHTML = step9;
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = ta_per_min_1;
  document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = ta_per_min_2;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  text-align: center;
}

;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />

  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <br /> String Price: <input type="text" id="string_tpc" value="0">
    <br /> Spider Eye Price: <input type="text" id="spider_eye_tpc" value="0">
    <br /> Iron Price: <input type="text" id="iron_tpc" value="0">
    <br /> Minions Tier 1: <input type="text" id="minions_tier_1_tpc" value="0"> Minion Amount 1: <input type="text" id="minions_1_tpc" value="0">
    <br /> Minions Tier 2: <input type="text" id="minions_tier_2_tpc" value="0"> Minion Amount 2: <input type="text" id="minions_2_tpc" value="0">
    <br />
    <button onclick="calculate_tpc()">Calculate</button>
    <br /> Current Coins per Tarantula: <span id="cpt_tpc">0</span>
    <br /> Coins per hour: <span id="cph_tpc">0</span>
    <br /> Coins per day: <span id="cpd_tpc">0</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Please be more clear - *which* values return `NaN`? Do any work? How do you reproduce the problem?

Comment: `document.getElementById("some_id").value` returns a string for text inputs, you need to convert them to numbers first then perform the calculations.

Comment: The Coins per Hour and Coins per Day are the ones that return "NaN" (Id's are cph_tpc and cpd_tpc). The only one that works is Current Coins per Tarantula (Id: cpt_tpc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is to use strings from input. The further effect is to get no values from the `switch` statements, because the value is a string and in all cases, you have numbers. The comparison is here strict, like `===`.

For unknown values, you could return the function and omit calculation with not given values.

```js
'use strict';

function calculate_tpc() {
  var string_cost = +document.getElementById("string_tpc").value;
  var spider_e_cost = +document.getElementById("spider_eye_tpc").value;
  var iron_cost = +document.getElementById("iron_tpc").value;
  var tami_1_tier = +document.getElementById("minions_tier_1_tpc").value;
  var tami_2_tier = +document.getElementById("minions_tier_2_tpc").value;
  var tami_1_amount = +document.getElementById("minions_1_tpc").value;
  var tami_2_amount = +document.getElementById("minions_2_tpc").value;
  var step1 = string_cost * 3.16;
  var step2 = iron_cost * 0.2;
  var step3 = step1 + step2 + spider_e_cost,
      ta_per_min_1,
      ta_per_min_2;
  
  switch (tami_1_tier) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      ta_per_min_1 = 2;
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      ta_per_min_1 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
      ta_per_min_1 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
      ta_per_min_1 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
      ta_per_min_1 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 11:
      ta_per_min_1 = 6;
      break;
    default: return;
  }
  switch (tami_2_tier) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      ta_per_min_2 = 2;
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      ta_per_min_2 = 2.3;
      break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
      ta_per_min_2 = 2.6;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
      ta_per_min_2 = 3.15;
      break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
      ta_per_min_2 = 4.1;
      break;
    case 11:
      ta_per_min_2 = 6;
      break;
    default: return;
  }
  var step4 = ta_per_min_1 * tami_1_amount;
  var step5 = ta_per_min_2 * tami_2_amount;
  var step6 = step4 + step5;
  var step7 = step6 * step3;
  var step8 = step7 * 60;
  var step9 = step8 * 24;
  document.getElementById("cpt_tpc").innerHTML = step3;
  document.getElementById("cph_tpc").innerHTML = step8;
  document.getElementById("cpd_tpc").innerHTML = step9;
  //document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = ta_per_min_1;
  //document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = ta_per_min_2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<br /> String Price: <input type="text" id="string_tpc" value="0">
<br /> Spider Eye Price: <input type="text" id="spider_eye_tpc" value="0">
<br /> Iron Price: <input type="text" id="iron_tpc" value="0">
<br /> Minions Tier 1: <input type="text" id="minions_tier_1_tpc" value="0"> Minion Amount 1: <input type="text" id="minions_1_tpc" value="0">
<br /> Minions Tier 2: <input type="text" id="minions_tier_2_tpc" value="0"> Minion Amount 2: <input type="text" id="minions_2_tpc" value="0">
<br />
<button onclick="calculate_tpc()">Calculate</button>
<br /> Current Coins per Tarantula: <span id="cpt_tpc">0</span>
<br /> Coins per hour: <span id="cph_tpc">0</span>
<br /> Coins per day: <span id="cpd_tpc">0</span>
```